# How to create a shell command for unhiding folders

Tags: android

I would like to create a shell command or get some code that i can use to unhide all folders in an android sd card. Also one that can hide would be usefull

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a shell command?, hidden folders on android start with ".", so you just use

```
File[] f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles()
```

and it will get you a list of all the folders, and files, even the ones that start with ".", so you just have to do whatever you want with a for loop, for example, for unhiding folders

```
for(int i=0; i<f.length; i++){
     if(f.getName().startsWith("."))
        f.renameTo(f.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + f.getName().replace(".", ""));
}
```

This will **ONLY** work for folders.

Comment: You can't just go renaming files or folders on your SD Card. They have that name for a reason. A good example is .android_secure. Rename that, and you lose access to all your apps that are installed on SD Card along with their data.

Comment: I didn't mean to rename all folders on SD Card. This is for renaming some specific directory, I missunderstand the question

Comment: My point stands, renaming a hidden folder like this doesn't *only* make it visible again, it will directly impact whatever app is expecting it to be there.